# How can I retrieve data from a QTableWidget to Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget in editable mode in which user puts in integer input , how can I generate a list of data entered in this table so as to perform operations on it  , here is my manual code for that:

```
def dataframe_generation_from_table(self,table):
    number_of_rows = table.rowCount()
    number_of_columns = table.columnCount()

    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date' : [] , str(self.final_lvl_of_analysis) :[],  'Value': []}) 

    for i in range(0,number_of_rows):
        for j in range(0,number_of_columns):
            tmp_item = table.item(i,j)
            tmp_df2 = pd.DataFrame( { 'Date' : [pd.to_datetime(table.horizontalHeaderItem(j).data())] , str(self.final_lvl_of_analysis) :[ str(table.verticalHeaderItem(i).data())], 'Value': [float(tmp_item.data(0))]})
            print tmp_df2
            tmp_df.update(tmp_df2, join = 'left', overwrite = False)

    return tmp_df
```

Also , I am using the following code for QTableWidget generation:

```
    self.pd_table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.groupBox_19)
    self.pd_table.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pd_table"))
    self.pd_table.setColumnCount(0)
    self.pd_table.setRowCount(0)
```

My specs are : pandas 0.18.1 , PyQt 4 and Python 2.7

Comment: Retrieve data always from the model of the view you are interested in.

Comment: @Trilarion kindly consider that I am not using QTableView , instead I am using QTableWidget , so please if you know a way to get data from a QTableWidget , do reply with an appropriate answer .

Comment: QTableWidget inherits from QTableView which inherits from QAbstractItemView which contains a QAbstractItemModel and there you have the model. I recommend interacting with the model or provide your own via QAbstractItemView.setModel.

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks for explaining the whole parentage , I had created my abstraction model for pasting in the QTableView for another table  , here it is https://ideone.com/do1Ho6 but I don't know how do I modify my model to take input  , if possible do help . I do have one query though , what is the use of QTableWidget if it isnot made specifically for user interaction and if I at-all need to use it ? Also when this appears to be a more common function , why hasn't there been included a method inside it already ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're overcomplicating it a little with the updates/joins. The simplest approach is to create the full-size `DataFrame` first (filled with `NaN`) and then assign the data to this:

```
def dataframe_generation_from_table(self,table):
    number_of_rows = table.rowCount()
    number_of_columns = table.columnCount()

    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame( 
                columns=['Date', str(self.final_lvl_of_analysis), 'Value'], # Fill columnets
                index=range(number_of_rows) # Fill rows
                ) 

    for i in range(number_of_rows):
        for j in range(number_of_columns):
            tmp_df.ix[i, j] = table.item(i, j).data()

    return tmp_df
```

The above code assigns data to it's location by the numerical index, so position 1,1 in the `QtTableWidget` will end up at 1,1 in the `DataFrame`. This way you don't need to worry about the column headers when moving data. If you want to change the column names you can do that when creating the `DataFrame`, changing the values passed into the `columns=` parameter.

If you want to change a column to `DateTime` format, you should be able to do this in a single operation after the loop with:

```
tmp_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime( tmp_df['Date'] )
```

Comment: what dataframe do you mean by df , here and also how can I ensure that the data is stored in correct cell ,i.e with its corresponding header labels ? thanks a lot for replying .

Comment: Typo sorry that should be `tmp_df`. See the edit for more description.

Comment: there seems to be an issue with your method apparently it generates an error "ValueError: cannot set by positional indexing with enlargement "   which can be resolved by using loc instead of ix , but that still does not solve my issue of referencing the horizontal and vertical labels for each QTableWidgetItem .

Answer (score 1):

The change from `.data()` to `.text()` eliminated the `ValueError`.

```
def saveFile(self):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    savePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Blood Hound", 
        "Testing.csv", "CSV files (*.csv)")        
    rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    columns = self.tableWidget.columnCount()        

    for i in range(rows):            
        for j in range(columns):                
            df.loc[i, j] = str(self.tableWidget.item(i, j).text())              
    df.to_csv((savePath), header = None, index = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# creates a new df from qtables dimensions,
# copies qtable (data & headers) to the df and returns the df
@staticmethod
def write_qtable_to_df(table):
    col_count = table.columnCount()
    row_count = table.rowCount()
    headers = [str(table.horizontalHeaderItem(i).text()) for i in range(col_count)]

    # df indexing is slow, so use lists
    df_list = []
    for row in range(row_count):
        df_list2 = []
        for col in range(col_count):
            table_item = table.item(row,col)
            df_list2.append('' if table_item is None else str(table_item.text()))
        df_list.append(df_list2)

    df = pandas.DataFrame(df_list, columns=headers)

    return df
```