# QtableWidget to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5

I have a two column qtablewidget that allows the user to add and delete rows through push buttons. I'd like to be able to read the contents of the table into a dataframe in order to count certain strings that are in the table. Here's an example of the table in the gui.
[image]

I want to read that table into a dataframe in order to analyze it.
Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
def dataframe_gen(self, table):
    num_rows = table.rowCount()
    num_cols = table.columnCount()

    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns = ['At_Bat_Num', 'Event'], index=range(num_rows))

    for i in range(num_rows):
        for j in range(num_cols):
            tmp_df.ix[i, j] = table.item(i, j).data()
```

I believe I need to store it into a dataframe before I can analyze it, as it only exists as the QTableWidget. Values are added and deleted from the gui.

---

Code:

```
def dataframe_gen(self):
    num_rows = self.tableWidget_Events.rowCount()
    num_cols = self.tableWidget_Events.columnCount()

    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns = ['At_Bat_Num', 'Event'], index=range(num_rows))
    for i in range(num_rows):
        for j in range(num_cols):
            tmp_df.ix[i, j] = self.tableWidget_Events.item(i, j)
    print(tmp_df)
```

Output:

```
                                          At_Bat_Num  \
0  <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x...   

                                               Event  
0  <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x...
```

Comment: What label do you mean?

Comment: Just a basic label that will take on the value of the count of a string. So a label saying there are 3 "a" items.

Comment: and what does the QTableWidget have to do with that topic? The code that you sample is not relevant.

Comment: The table is a QTableWidget. It doesn't exist outside of that. It's created only from the gui. I've edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: The question is duplicated because your goal is to calculate the frequency of the elements, and establish it in some QLabel, the first task has many solutions that are shown in the link, and the second task is trivial.

Comment: I disagree. The first task is getting the table into a pandas dataframe. Tha's what I need help with, not the rest, as I stated in the question.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680981/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-a-qtablewidget

Comment: That's what the code above is based on. Except it doesn't seem to be working. To try and correct it, I'm just trying to print out each item in the table before I store them. Right now, all that's being printed is this: <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x0000017A98DD0A68>

Comment: execute `print(tmp_df)` after loops

Comment: I've attached the code I ran along with the results from the print statement.

Comment: change `tmp_df.ix[i, j] = self.tableWidget_Events.item(i, j)` to `tmp_df.ix[i, j] = self.tableWidget_Events.item(i, j).text()`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.